# Reading Hong Kong Supplementary Character Set in python 3

Tags: python, utf-8, character-encoding, nlp

I have a hkscs dataset that I am trying to read in python 3. Below code

```
encoding = 'big5hkscs'
lines = []
num_errors = 0
for line in open('file.txt'):
    try:
        lines.append(line.decode(encoding))
    except UnicodeDecodeError as e:
        num_errors += 1
```

It throws me error `UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0xae in position 0: invalid start byte`. Seems like there is a non utf-8 character in the dataset that the code is not able to decode.

I tried adding `errors = ignore` in this line
`lines.append(line.decode(encoding, errors='ignore'))`

But that does not solve the problem.

Can anyone please suggest?

Comment: We can't solve this problem without seeing the file in question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If a text file contains text encoded with an encoding that is not the default encoding, the encoding must be specified when opening the file to avoid decoding errors:

```
encoding = 'big5hkscs'
path = 'file.txt'
with open(path, 'r', encoding=encoding,) as f:
    for line in f:
        # do something with line
```

Alternatively, the file may be opened in binary mode, and text decoded afterwards:

```
encoding = 'big5hkscs'
path = 'file.txt'
with open(path, 'rb') as f:
    for line in f:
       decoded = line.decode(encoding)
       # do something with decoded text
```

In the question, the file is opened without specifying an encoding, so its contents are automatically decoded with the default encoding - apparently UTF-8 in the is case.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like if I do NOT add the `except` clause `except UnicodeDecodeError as e`, it works fine

```
encoding = 'big5hkscs'
lines = []
path = 'file.txt'
with open(path, encoding=encoding, errors='ignore') as f:
    for line in f:
        line = '\t' + line
        lines.append(line)
```

Answer (score 0):

The answer of *[snakecharmerb](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59421968/2758823)* is correct, but possibly you need an explanation.

You didn't write it in the original question, but I assume you have the error on the `for` line. In this line you are decoding the file from UTF-8 (probably the default on your environment, so not on Windows), but later you are trying to decode it again. So the error is not about decoding `big5hkscs`, but about opening the file as text.

As in the good answer of *snakecharmerb* (second part), you should open the file as binary, so without decoding texts, and then you can decode the text with `line.decode(encoding)`. Note: I'm not sure you can read *lines* on a binary file. In this manner you can still catch the errors, e.g. to write a message. Else the normal way is to decode at `open()` time, but then you loose the ability to fall back and to get users better error message (e.g. line number).